# facebook messanger link sharing only working in mobile, not working for web

Tags: php, jquery, facebook

Facebook messanger share link script only working for mobile, not working in desktop web browser/desktop facebook messanger..

I found following link for web fb messanger, but its saying expired link..

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog/ (expired link)
```

My code Snippet:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?app_id=123456789&link=<?=$referal_url?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?=BASE_IMAGE?>FB_Messenger.png" class="img-responsive"> </a>
```

Its only working for mobile app, but not working desktop browser app

please suggest me php script to share any link on mobile as well as desktop fb messanger apps

thanks in advance

Comment: _“but its saying expired link”_ - explain what you mean by that. _“Its only working for mobile app, but not working desktop browser app”_ - what, with that code? Should be the other way around, because the Send Dialog is not supposed to work on mobile, the documentation says.